# SQL to get the most recent record for each user

Tags: sql

Tried to think how to generalize my question and just couldn't think of something (which is perhaps why I googling has noe provided a solution yet).

So I'm putting my question in terms of a USERS table and a COMMENTS table where I want to get the most recent COMMENT ***for each user***.

**USERS**

```
| ID | NAME |
-------------
| 01 | BOB  |
-------------
| 02 | JEN  |
-------------
```

**COMMENTS**

```
| EMP_ID | UPDATED    |
-----------------------
| 01     | 12/05/2011 |   <== I WANT THIS
-----------------------
| 01     | 11/29/2011 |
-----------------------
| 02     | 12/01/2011 |   <== ...AND THIS
-----------------------
| 02     | 11/27/2011 |
```

---

I've tried something like this...

```
select e.date from USERS u 
join EMPLOYEES e on e.emp_id=u.id 
where emp_id in (select emp_id from TIMESHEETS where emp_id=u.id order by date fetch first 1 row only)
```

...and it works, but is horrendously slow.

(We're using DB2 and so I have Common Tables at our disposal)

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - Select 'n' greatest elements in group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538725/sql-select-n-greatest-elements-in-group)

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.name
     , u.id
     , c.text
     , c.updated
  from users u
left
  join ( select cm.emp_id
              , max(cm.updated) mostRecentCommentDate
           from comments cm
          group
             by cm.emp_id ) recentComments
    on  recentComments.emp_id = u.id
left
  join comments c
    on c.emp_id = u.id
   and c.updated = recentComments.mostRecentCommentDate
```

A potential problem here is when a user has more than one comment on the same day as thier most recent comment. It can be resolved, but you'll need to provide criteria for how to determine the desired row. The above query will give a row for each comment on the most recent comment date. Too bad it's not a datetime field...

Comment: Chris thanks - I'll look into this. (My USERS/COMMENTS thing is a simplfication of the real situation -- in reality I am dealing with a datetime field!) I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again Chris - I considered your approach, but in the end I looked again at the aproach I took in my original SQL. The SQL I included in my question was greatly simplified. In reality I have three joins and fairly large where clause.

I found that the correlated sub-query approach was actually very fast when I was careful about my where clause, and when I made sure that where the subquery correlated with the outer query, it did so on a result set that was greatly reduced by filtering.